# several class different in one input?, how is it?

Tags: html, css

how is puting tow class different in one input?
 
classes is: auto and date.
did is this true?

```
    <input type="text" name="date_go" class="auto" class="date">
```

Comment: *did is this true?* What does this mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't do that. A HTML element should contain **unique attributes only**.

In my experience, browsers tend to just use the first or last one defined in the markup ([what does your browser do?](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/c4CDk/))...

[image: Chrome example]

<sup>Google Chrome has decided to use the first attribute defined in the markup when building the DOM.</sup>

Instead, do this...

```
<input type="text" name="date_go" class="auto date">
```

...or in other words, if you want multiple classes, join them together with a space in the `class` attribute.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/aMCp5/).